# Determining Transitive Dependencies

Tags: dependencies

I am working on figuring out partial and transitive dependencies.  The Transitive ones are really confusing me because I can see a transitive dependency on nearly all of these.[image]

The partial dependencies are Agree_No -> Agree_Date, Cust_No -> Cust_Name and Cust_Phone; Serial_No -> Item_Name and Item_Rate.

The Transitive Dependencies that I see are Item_Rate -> Item_Name.  But could Cust_Phone be a transitive to Cust_Name and the Agree_No/Date?  Are there others I am missing?

Comment: Sometimes the data shows there's no FD. But data consistent with a FD is also consistent with no FD. So you have to tell us what the FDs are, or if there is a convention by which this table is constructed to communicate FDs then you have to tell us what it is. Some FD info can be derived by knowing the CKs, because the FDs determine the CKs.

Comment: Why do you think that those FDs hold? Why do you think they are or might be transitive?

Answer (score 1):

A FD (functional dependency) X -> Z is transitive when there exists a Y such that X -> Y AND Y -> Z AND NOT Y -> X AND NOT Y = Z. (X, Y & Z are attribute sets.)

There can be lots of X, Y & Zs where X -> Y AND Y -> Z but X -> Z is not transitive because Y -> X. Eg this happens whenever X and Y are CKs (candidate keys). (Because CKs functionally determine all attributes--each determines the other and Z.) And there can be lots of transitive FDs. Eg this happens whenever there is a FD whose attributes are non-prime. (Because a CK determines that FD's determinant which itself doesn't determine the CK--if it did then *it* would be a CK, which with non-prime attributes it isn't.) The FDs among all those ones that are important for normalization are transitive FDs of non-prime attributes on CKs when a relation is in 2NF. Because it is always possible to losslessly decompose such a relation to components free of them, ie in 3NF.